# C++ standards: is there a result object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
int foo() { return 0; }
int x = foo() + 1;
```

[This](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#5.sentence-4) says the `foo()` function call expression has no result object:

> a non-discarded prvalue that is used to compute the value of an operand of a built-in operator or a prvalue that has type cv void has no result object

I read this as follows: (a non-discarded prvalue that is used to compute the value of an operand of a built-in operator) or (a prvalue that has type cv void) has no result object. The first case is ours.

On the other hand, [that](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2.sentence-4) talks about the result object of the function call:

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand

I read this as follows: the return statement initializes the (glvalue result) or (prvalue result object) of the ... function call by copy-initialization from the operand. The second case is ours.

So what exactly does `return 0;` initialize? Perhaps, it is meant that the temporary from [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#3.sentence-1) is being initialized?

Comment: you omitted the important part and replaced it with `...` which changes the meaning. "... that has type cv void ..."

Comment: I've parsed the sentence as follows: (a non-discarded prvalue that is used to compute the value of an operand of a built-in operator) or (a prvalue that has type cv void) has no result object. Since `void` isn't the case, I've omitted the second part

Comment: no native speaker either, but consider "Don't eat apples or oranges that are rotten" vs "Don't eat (apples) or (oranges that are rotten)" you cannot add `()` there without changing the meaning

Comment: even if i am wrong you should make the quote complete, not leave out half sentences

Comment: Done. What is your read of the sentence?

Comment: my read is "The result object of a [...mumbo jumbo...] that has type cv void has no result object" ;)

Comment: So, (a non-discarded prvalue that is used to compute the value of an operand of a built-in operator) or (a prvalue) that has type cv void has no result object? The second case subsumes the first - that seems odd. Secondly, there would be "have type", not "has type". Edit: strike out the last bit, it would still be "has type", probably

Comment: i am really not sure what it means, my whole point was that you have to quote the complete sentence. To rerphase it (which skipping parts is) you first need to know how to interpret it, while I understood the question being about how to interpret it

Comment: same with the other quote btw

Comment: Are there any glvalues here? Fine, will edit

Comment: I'm willing to wager that the quote isn't even relevant as it is about prvalues whereas I'd see the zero clearly as an xvalue (there's absolutely no obstacles to immedialtely reuse a literal's resources, are there?). That's even moreso the case as the text, a paragraph earlier, explicitly states that `foo()` is an xvalue. Anyway, what's the actual problem? Clearly, nothing is initialized in an integer literal, or when returning the literal, or adding another literal. The one thing that is being initialized is the integer `x` (lvalue).

Comment: Either result has the same observable behaviour. The two readings are a difference without a distinction.

Comment: @Damon, an xvalue must have an identity (it must denote an existing object). 0 is a prvalue. The function call expression that returns non-reference is also a prvalue.

Comment: @Caleth Looks like a defect to me. The standard requires the `return` statement to initialize a result object that does not exist.

Comment: I think could be just fixed editorially like _the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object **(if any)**_

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But then *what* does it do in this case? Does it even initialize?

Comment: In `one() + two()`, we don't really care if there are 1, 2 or 3 `int` objects, only that the whole expression has the value `3`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's a defect. The correction can be as follows:

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue ***result*** of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand

A prvalue function call can have no *result object*. It always has a *result* if the return type is not *cv* `void`.

Comment: _result_ of a prvalue is a value. `void` has empty set of values. So, `void` prvalue function call doesn't have a _result_.

Comment: Fixed. Well, it always has a result in the context where "result" would be used: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2.sentence-4.